If a singular square matrix is multiplied by a non-singular square matrix, the null space of the result is what?
If a non-singular square matrix $B$ is multiplied by a singular square matrix $A$ of the same order, the nullspace of the resulting matrix $C=B\times A$ or $C'=A \times B$ remains unchanged from that of $A$?
Suppose that $Null(C)$ and $Null'(C')$ refer to the nullspace and the left nullspace of $C$ and $C'$, respectively.
Does the equality $Null(C)=Null(A)$ or $Null'(C')=Null'(A)$ hold without any influence from matrix $B$? In other words, do the entries in $Null(C)$ or $Null'(C')$ not contain the entries from B? Especially, $A$ is a nilpotent matrix.
If so, is there a theorem or corollary that can demonstrate this point?
